# ListView add image button with CommandName, Visible, CommandArgument dynamically by calling Eval()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Attached desire output (Record(s)))
right now i can add multiple links to Records column but cannot add muliple image button  with command name and command arguments
[image]
I tried to create image button dynamically by calling GetRecordLinks(Eval("Records"))` from code behind, below is my code

```
<asp:ListView ID="Student" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Student_ItemCommand" OnItemDeleting="Student_ItemDeleting" OnItemDataBound="Student_OnItemDataBound">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table class="DataGrid">
                <tr class="HeaderRow">                                               
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Name</td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">Class(s)</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Sex</td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">Recordss</td>
                     <td style="width: 150px;">Status</td>
                    <td style="width: 30px; text-align: center;">Activate/Delete</td>                                                
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>                    
                <td>
                    <b><%# Eval("StudentLastName") %>, <%# Eval("StudentFirstName") %> <%# Eval("StudentMiddleName") %></b>                        
                </td>
                <td>                        
                    <%# JoinStringList(Eval("class")) %>
                </td>
                <td> <%# Eval("sex") %></td>
                <td>
                    <%# GetRecordLinks(Eval("Records")) %>                        
                </td>                  
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("StatusID").ToString()=="0"?"Inactive":"Active" %>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">                        

                   <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="img/Refresh.png" ID="StudentActive"  runat="server" CommandName="Active" Visible='<%#Eval("StatusID").ToString()=="0"?true:false%>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StudentGUID") %>' />                                                                
                    <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="img/delete.png" ID="StudentDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Visible='<%#Eval("StatusID").ToString()=="0"?false:true%>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StudentGUID") %>' />                                                
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

`GetRecordLinks` method below

I want to append asp:ImageButton with `CommandName` ,`Visible`,`CommandArgument` for each record of student.
for eaxmple if student A have 5 records each five record in a cell, should have 5 imagebutton with iteamcommand so that i can delete or activate the record depend on use wish.

```
public string GetRecordLinks(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            List<AppointmentDoc> docs = (List<AppointmentDoc>)obj;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                                              
            foreach (AppointmentDoc rec in docs)
            {                    
                sb.Append("<a target='_blank' href=\"result.ashx?uuid=" + rec.UUID.ToString() + "\">" + rec.Name.Replace("student", "").Trim() + " (" + rec.SignedBy + ")" + (rec.staffSigned ? "*" : "") + "</a><br/>");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return "";
 }
```

---

hope understand my question
let me know if any queries

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a PlaceHolder and add your ImageButtons to it. First, replace:

```
<td>
    <%# GetRecordLinks(Eval("Records")) %>                        
</td>
```

with:

```
<td>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phRecords" runat="server" />
</td>
```

Then in code-behind:

```
void Student_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    PlaceHolder phRecords = e.Item.FindControl("phRecords") as PlaceHolder;
    ImageButton imgButton = new ImageButton();
    // Set the ImageButton properties here
    ph.Controls.Add(imgButton);
}
```

That would add a single button. You can put the ImageButton creation code in a loop to add several of them in the same cell.

You would also have to recreate those ImageButtons on every postback, so you may need to bind your data in the Page_Load method.

Comment: Thanks Connors... I used PlacehHolder as you said and crated link and image button dynamically.. i changed listview to repeater...but i have issue now,image button which i created dyanmically is not fired to iteamcommand, I binded same method in postback.. still not working

Comment: Can you keep the `ListView` and set the `CommandName` (and `CommandArgument` if needed) of the ImageButton? It should trigger the `ItemCommand` event.

Comment: thanks... I used itemdatabound and iteamcreated to create all the buttons in repaeter dynamically everything works fine.. Thanks